# Can't generate Javacard applet

Tags: java, applet, converters, javacard

I am trying To create a Javacard applet from my source code.

So when i type the following command:

```
converter -debug -verbose 
-exportpath C:\java_card_kit-2_2_2-windows\java_card_kit-2_2_2\api_export_files 
-classdir C:\smartcard-with-fingerprint-auth-master\smartcard-with-fingerprint-auth-master\Osiris\bin 
-applet 0x01:0x02:0x03:0x04:0x05:0x06:0x07:0x08:0x09:0x00 Osiris osiris 0x01:0x02:0x03:0x04:0x05:0x06:0x07:0x08:0x09:0x00:0x00 1.0
```

I receive:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: 
 com/sun/javacard/converter/Converter
```

Could any one help me to find out from where comes the problem?

Comment: You may have a library in class path that was failed to load in JVM. Add System.out.println or use try catch throw to locate the class that need to be fixed.

Comment: What value do you use for the `JC_HOME` environment variable? Given your command line it should be set to `C:\java_card_kit-2_2_2-windows\java_card_kit-2_2_2`.

Comment: resolved! i would like to thank you for your response

Comment: Hello, my applet is ready but i can't download it into my smart card.
I am using gp.exe but even when i try to execute any command of gp for exemple (>gp -list) i get 6D00 as answer. Can any one help me please?

Answer (score 0):

Older Java Card Development Kits need environment variable `JC_HOME` set. It should point to the kit installation directory.

In your particular case it needs to be set to:

`C:\java_card_kit-2_2_2-windows\java_card_kit-2_2_2`

Newer Java Card SDKs determine this path at runtime.

Good luck with your project!